# How to use Ceisum EntityCollection

Tags: cesiumjs

I am trying to use `Cesium.EntityCollecion` to manage some Entity Object. But it can't show on Earth.

Here is my code:

```
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");
const collection = new Cesium.EntityCollection();
viewer.entities.add(collection);
collection.add({
    id: 1,
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(118.0, 35.0),
    point: {
        pixelSize: 100,
        color: Cesium.Color.RED,
    },
});
```

Is that problem caused by `viewer.entities.add(collection)`? Cesium version is 1.109.

If I use:

```
viewer.entities.add({
    id: 1,
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(118.0, 35.0),
    point: {
        pixelSize: 100,
        color: Cesium.Color.RED,
    },
});
```

this entity can show up correctly, but I need to manage different group of entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the real problem.
You have to add an instance of Entity into the viewer.entities.
To manage different group of entities, you can use CustomDataSource.
Below is sample code.

```
const { Cartesian3, CustomDataSource, Viewer } = Cesium;

const viewer = new Viewer("cesiumContainer");

const group1 = new CustomDataSource("group1");
const group2 = new CustomDataSource("group2");

viewer.dataSources.add(group1);
viewer.dataSources.add(group2);

group1.entities.add({
    id: 1,
    position: Cartesian3.fromDegrees(118.0, 35.0),
    point: {
        pixelSize: 100,
        color: Cesium.Color.RED
    }
});

group2.entities.add({
    id: 1,
    position: Cartesian3.fromDegrees(140.0, 35.0),
    point: {
        pixelSize: 100,
        color: Cesium.Color.BLUE
    }
});
```